# Error while debugging in visual studio 2015

Tags: debugging

I upgraded my windows 7 to windows 10, and i installed visual studio 2015, but when i debug any windows form application or web application (new or old), there is a sound appears in background like an error sound, and the debugging not continue

Comment: Have you heard the sound while using VS before? Are any messages, prompts or output shown?

Comment: No, only this sound appears when i press start debug, and only the output is "The program '[27220] myapp.vshost.exe' has exited with code -1073740771 (0xc000041d)"

Comment: does it throws any error?

Comment: i am trying this code now: static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            string str = "Hello world";
            int id = 20;
            int id2 = 10;
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

I found this dll C:\Users\hpMain\AppData\Local\IVsoft\qbwkezjs.dll when i deleted it it is working